# How to save a record with two fields disabled on the PM301000 screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Good afternoon everyone,

I need your help, I want to record one or several records on the PM301000 Projects screen in the detail tab, Cost Budget.
When recording one or more records, two Mark for PO and Vendor ID fields must be disabled. When the condition of the Mark for PO field is equal to true.

I have used the RowPersisting event and it disables it but when I modify or leave the registry the fields are enabled again.

Please help me or tell me how I should do it, my code is as follows.

Thanks in advance.

```
namespace PX.Objects.PM
{
    public class PMBudgetExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.PM.PMBudget>
    {
        #region UsrVendorID


        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]

        [PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("VENDOR", typeof(Search<VendorR.bAccountID, Where<VendorR.type, Equal<BAccountType.vendorType>,
                                        And<VendorR.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>>>>), 
            typeof(VendorR.acctCD), new Type[] { typeof(VendorR.acctCD), typeof(VendorR.acctName) })]
        public virtual int? UsrVendorID { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrVendorID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrVendorID> { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrMarkforPO

        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Mark for PO")]  

        public virtual bool? UsrMarkforPO { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrMarkforPO : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrMarkforPO> { }
        #endregion
    }
}

namespace PX.Objects.PM
{
    public class ProjectEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
    {      
        #region Event Handlers       
        protected void PMCostBudget_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            PMCostBudget newRow = (PMCostBudget)e.Row;
            if (newRow == null) return;
            PMBudgetExt newRowE = PXCache<PMBudget>.GetExtension<PMBudgetExt>(newRow);

            if (Base.CostBudget.Cache.AllowUpdate == true)
            {
                if (newRowE.UsrMarkforPO == true)
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<PMBudgetExt.usrMarkforPO>(cache, newRow, false);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<PMBudgetExt.usrVendorID>(cache, newRow, false);                    
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image: Ima01]

[image: Ima02]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowPersisting` event executes only on save event. Therefore it's not suited for setting the field states. You will get better results with `RowSelected` event which is executed everytime a record is selected to be displayed on screen. You should set the state on every callback whether it is enabled or disabled. Also, the event should be declared on the same DAC type you are using to set the field state so the cache object match.

```
    public void PMBudget_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
    {
      if (del != null)
      {
         del(sender, e);
      }

      bool isFieldEnabled = [your_condition];
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<PMBudget.field>(sender, e.Row, isFieldEnabled);
    }
```